# Fortnightly challenge - Feature request - make it a competition

Tags: feature-request, challenge

Being a competitive soul. I'm interested in there being a winner for the Fortnightly challenge.

Ha! you exclaim, chasly would say that wouldn't he? He has a very successful question running at the moment!

It may seem that I want it for that reason. That's true but it isn't my primary motivation.

I entered into the challenge because I assumed it *was* a competition. I like competitions even if I don't win them.

**Request**

Can we be shown a score for the top three questions. It could be in terms of views, or answers, or total up-votes on question and answers (my personal favourite), or it could be some other measure.

**Note**

I realise it is a lot of work to extract the statistics and I don't want to be unreasonable. I'm not asking for the whole thing to be exhaustively analysed and typed out, just the top three.

Comment: We currently auto-generate the challenge posts, including the results. I'm sure the generator could be updated to do statistics, if necessary.

Comment: 7 hours ago: "Would it be possible to omit the numbering? I believe it gives the impression that the questions are arranged in order of merit, with the 'winner' being number 1".

Comment: You changed your mind ?

Comment: @Vincent - At the moment, the numbering gives a false impression. It suggests that there already is a winner. I think we should either remove the numbering altogether or make it mean something.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to declaring a winner based on *asking* questions, I propose that we also have a winner for *answering* questions. Because a lot of the time, the answer is much more useful than the question. This could be judged based on votes, as with the questions. Pretty much just whoever gets the most upvotes for answers to questions with the challenge tag wins.

Plus, this would give people more options for participating in the challenge. If you can't think of a good question, maybe you can think of a good answer, and that's just as useful, and something for which you deserve credit.

Comment: Yes - that is an excellent idea. I know that my own answers usually score low. I'd be interested to see what makes for a good answer by observing people who consistently do well.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see the need, but if we did do this I'd suggest just ranking by total upvotes-downvotes on all questions (maybe on answers too). This encourages quality over quantity.

Comment: That sounds like a good measure. I suggest totalling net votes for the question plus the answers.

Answer (score 2):

I've wondered about the stats of the fortnightly challenges myself.  I'd be very curious to see them, whatever they may be.

There wouldn't be any rewards obviously, other than reputation gained from questions/answers.  No badges either because that requires code changes.

Comment: Yes - even if no-one was officially declared winner it would be interesting to do our own comparisons and see what sort of question attracts answers.